# AngularJS ng-click doesnt work from partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I want to create the step by step actions without inserting something into the address line.
And I stumbled upon a problem.

Here is my parent page:

```
<html ng-app="Steps">
<head>
    <script src="../../Content/script/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/script/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/script/Partials2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="StepCtrl">
    <div id="container" ng-template-controller-action="Steps/StepOne">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my js:

```
var step = angular.module("Steps", []);

step.directive("ngTemplateControllerAction", function ($compile, $http) {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $http({ method: "GET", url: attrs.ngTemplateControllerAction }).
            success(function (data) {
                $(element).html($compile(data)($scope));
            });
        }
    };
});

step.controller("StepCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.goToSecondStep = function () {
        console.log(1);
    };

    $scope.goToFirstStep = function () {
        console.log(1);
    };
});
```

partial view1:

```
<div>First step</div>
<button class="btn" ng-click="goToSecondStep()">Second Step</button>
```

partial view2:

```
<div>Second step</div>
<button class="btn" ng-click="goToFirstStep()">First Step</button>
```

So, when I click the Second step button i want to see '1' in console, but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but this can be done easily using `ng-include`

`<div id="container" ng-include="pathToTheViewOnServer">
</div>`

The `pathToTheViewOnServer` can be set in scope

`$scope.pathToTheViewOnServer = Steps/StepOne;`

or directly providing path in `ng-include`

`<div id="container" ng-include="'Steps/StepOne'">
</div>`

Comment: But how i can compile partial view? Problem is why ng-click="goToSecondStep()" doesnt work.

Comment: Partial views included using ng-include are automatically compiled.

Comment: There is a little problem. First partial view load properly. When I click the button value of '$scope.pathToTheViewOnServer' changes. But nothing happens. I still see the first partial view.

Comment: So... i find a problem with $scope. In my partial view there is own controller. But watcher waits for the change of variable form its scope. And this why nothing happens... Still looking for a solution how to change the external variable inside the internal controller.